# Draggable modal name / implementatoin?

Tags: reactjs

just curious and trying to implement a "modal" that's frequently used in apps. However i don't know the name of that element and don't know the best way to implement it, here's some images of what i'm talking about :

[image: State 1]

[image: State 2]

This is just a wireframe but i'm sure you get the idea, so two questions :

- How is this called
- How to implement it using React (best practice)